# How can I count combinations of text across different columns in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a worksheet in Excel 2010 (see below for sample) where the column headings are:   Solicitor, Net Fees, Case Type

[image]

I am trying to work out how to count the number of times each case type appears for each solicitor. It seems so simple but I can't work it out.

Ideally it would be via a pivot table so that it could be presented in a table, with the solicitors listed in the rows and the case types in the columns and corresponding count values in the body of the table. If there are better solutions though, that is fine.

When I tried creating a pivot table as described, there was just no option for adding Count (or anything else) into the Values area, I presume because I'm working with text fields?

I can't believe I can't work this out for myself, but I'm really struggling so any assistance will be much appreciated. I've searched for the answer to this every way I can think of, so apologies if it's a question that has been asked before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a Pivot table, just put the Case type in both the Columns and Values:

[image]